# vb4android Alternative for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vb4android

Is there any alternative to [vb4android](http://code.google.com/p/vb4android/) for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to develop for Mac OS X and not iOS?

Take a look at the new Delphi XE2 which supports Windows, Max OS X and iOS.
There is also LiveCode which develops for all platforms.

If you are looking to develop apps on portable devices iOS (iPhone,iPod, iPad) and Android then try NS Basic/App Studio and PhoneGap. Or RhoMobile or Appcelerator. They run semi-native apps using javascript.

Widget

Comment: I was looking for some GUI builder like vb4android to develop using Simple. **:)**